# Have read_csv2() guess date types

Tags: r

I tried using `read_csv2()` from the `readr` package to import a `.csv` file containing one or more columns that only hold dates. I expected that `read_csv2()` would guess that these columns hold dates but I get `col_character()` as column specification.

I cannot specify in advance what column should be date type because I am importing many tables of which the names are listed in a configuration table (I use a loop to import every table listed in that configuration table). Thus my question: Is there a way to have `read_csv2()` properly guess date types?

I tried saving the dates in different date formats such that there would be no ambiguity about the date format from the original file but to no avail.

**Example**

Data

```
> t_table

id       date colour
1 31/12/2015  green
2 31/01/2016    red
3 29/02/2016 orange
4 31/03/2016   blue
```

Code for importing

```
read_csv2("t_table.csv")
```

Column specifications as a result of the above way of importing

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  id = col_integer(),
  date = col_character(),
  colour = col_character()
```

One can see that column `date` is character type.

**UPDATE**

I found one way to solve my problem: in the input file, use date format (I do this via excel) `yyyy-mm-dd` rather than `dd/mm/yyyy`. Note that `dd-mm-yyyy` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question suggests that both the name and position of the column containing dates cannot be anticipated. If so, a little hack might be to identify the column containing the `/` symbol and convert it to `date` format.
It is not the automatic 'guesswork' you are after, but may be of some use.

```
find<-grep("[/]", t_table)

t_table[,find]<-as.Date(t_table[,find],'%d/%m/%Y')

str(t_table)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ id    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4
# $ date  : Date, format: "2015-12-31" "2016-01-31" "2016-02-29" "2016-03-31"
# $ colour: Factor w/ 4 levels "blue","green",..: 2 4 3 1
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. Your idea might come in handy. As the tables are configuration tables (thus, designed by myself), however, I'll simply go for the different formatting workaround (see update in my post) this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date format used to guess dates with the locale option:

read_csv2("t_table.csv", locale = locale(date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"))

See also:
https://readr.tidyverse.org/articles/locales.html